# I cannot find the source for the insert trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

I'm looking into a issue in salesforce. I can see a insert trigger for a object being called in Debug logs. But, i couldn't find what is the source for the actual trigger.

There's no workflow for this object. Also, there's no references of this object in Apex, trigger for doing insert operation.

Its very confusing. can anyone help me out?

Comment: Its possible its being called from a class.

Comment: If you look at the object in Setup, it should tell you what triggers reference it. From there you should be able to view the trigger itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the trigger in context and click on Show dependencies you can see the classes referenced in the trigger. Debug logs may or may not show all based on how fine you have set the filters and if the max size of the log is reached the text may get truncated sometimes.

[image]

[image]